# angular force me to make variables on window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to follow angularjs recommendation (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> While the example above is simple, it will not scale to large
>   applications. Instead we recommend that you break your application to
>   multiple modules like this:
>
> A service module, for service declaration A directive module, for
>   directive declaration A filter module, for filter declaration And an
>   application level module which depends on the above modules, and which
>   has initialization code.

So I've created services.js file that only contains:

```
window.myservices = angular.module('services', []);
```

And then I added a few services where each service file starts with:

```
window.myservices.factory('service1', function() {
    ....
});
```

I made the same for filters.js and directives.js.

In my app.js file I made:

```
window.App = angular.module('app', ['services', 'filters', 'directives']).
    // run \ config \ whatever
```

How can I do it without making variables on window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stewie said, you can use `angular.modue('service',[])`;

However you only need to do this in the first loaded file, like so:

file1.js

```
var mod = angular.module('service',['dependancy']);
```

file2.js

```
var mod = angular.module('service');
```

index.html

```
<script src="/scripts/file1.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/file2.js"></script>
```

Another option is to use namespaces...

file1.js

```
var mod = angular.module('service.part1',[]);
```

file2.js

```
var mod = angular.module('service.part2',[]);
```

main.js

```
var mod = angular.moduel('service', ['service.part1','service.part2']);
```

EDIT (plunker):

http://plnkr.co/edit/i75A5CQeSptQjaxvR8qi?p=preview

Comment: I don't think you understood me. I am asking about how to create many services and how to "attach" them into one services module that located in different js file.

Comment: @Naor, the services are "attached" in the array that is passed into `angular.module()`. The first argument defines a module, and the second is an array of it's dependencies.  So you don't need to reference them on `window.*`

Comment: Ok, I think I understood what you are saying. But if I have X services, this eventually will cause creating of X modules while I only need one module. More then that, each time I create a new service, I'll have to remember to add this module to the main services module..

Comment: @Naor, you can do it all in one module, if you leave out the second argument (array) for all but the first referenced file. i.e. `andular.module('service')`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for globals at all:

```js
// Define your services
angular.module('services', [])
  .factory('service1', function(){})
  .factory('service2', function(){});

// Define you main app module and specify the dependencies
angular.module('MyApp', ['services']);
```

Comment: This is fine only when I declare all my services in single file. I want to separate to files and put each service in different file. But in each file, how do I refer to the services module? I need to write something like: (???).factory('service1', function(){})